# Fecha mínima y fecha máxima en vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, formularios, date, webforms, datepicker

Tengo un formulario de reserva para hotel con 2 campos de fecha: uno para la entrada (CHECKIN) y otro para la salida (CHECKOUT). Hice dos bloques de javascript de CASI el mismo código; lo que cambia es la fecha de salida mínima que es UN DÍA DESPUÉS de la fecha actual. Todo debe ser generado dinámicamente.

Le cambié el nombre a las variables en el segundo bloque, el del CHECKOUT (Salida) ya que, al parecer sobreescribe al primer bloque y lo sigue sobreescribiendo. Están apuntando a diferentes IDs (#); cada campo de fecha tiene un ID diferente.

No sé cómo hacer para que el primer bloque funcione y se pueda elegir como mínimo 2 días después de la fecha actual y no permitir que elijan una fecha de salida anterior a la fecha de entrada, lo cual sería un absurdo. Abajo el código.

```
<input type="date" id="checkIn" name="checkIn" required>
<input type="date" id="checkOut" name="checkOut" required>

<!--Scripts for CHECKIN date-->
   <script>
    function formatISOLocal(d) {
        let z = n => ('0' + n).slice(-2);
        return d.getFullYear() + '-' + z(d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + z(d.getDate());
        }

        window.onload = function() {
        let inp = document.querySelector('#checkIn');
        let d = new Date();
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2); /*Minimum date for CHECKIN*/
        inp.min = formatISOLocal(d);
        inp.defaultValue = inp.min;
        d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 3);
        inp.max = formatISOLocal(d);
        }
</script> 
<!--Intenté quitando las etiquetas script al final del 1er. bloque y del inicio del 2º bloque, pero nada.-->
<!--Scripts for CHECKOUT date-->
<script>
    function formatISOLocal1(e) {
        let a = o => ('0' + o).slice(-2);
        return e.getFullYear() + '-' + a(e.getMonth()+1) + '-' + a(e.getDate());
        }

        window.onload = function() {
        let out = document.querySelector('#checkOut');
        let e = new Date();
        e.setDate(e.getDate() + 3); /*Minimum date for CHECKOUT*/
        out.min = formatISOLocal1(e);
        out.defaultValue = out.min;
        e.setMonth(e.getMonth() + 4);
        out.max = formatISOLocal1(e);
        }
</script>
```

Para que lo puedan ver más cómodamente, les comparto mi [codepen](https://codepen.io/limakid/pen/QWmjjQj?editors=1000). Orientaciones, por favor.

Comment: La propiedad `onload`, del segundo bloque, sobrescribe la que declaraste en el primero y siempre se va a ejecutar solo esa última. Una opción rápida es unir los códigos de ambas funciones en una sola y no necesitas una función `formatISOLocal()` para cada campo, ahí no es donde está el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Agrega un evento `change` en tu `checkIn` para escuchar los cambios. Cuando se establezca la fecha de entrada, completa el campo de salida con la fecha que resulta al sumarle un día al campo de entrada, y establece el atributo `min` para que impida seleccionar otra fecha. Te adjunto un breve ejemplo:

```js
var checkIn = document.getElementById('checkIn');
var checkOut = document.getElementById('checkOut');

checkIn.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var checkInDate = new Date(checkIn.value);
    var checkOutDate = new Date(checkInDate.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    checkOut.value =checkOutDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    checkOut.min = checkOutDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
});
```

```html
<input type="date" id="checkIn" name="checkIn" required>
<input type="date" id="checkOut" name="checkOut" required>
```

Ten en cuenta que el atributo `min` de un input de tipo `date` [no es soportado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929297/html-5-input-type-date-control-max-date-is-not-working-in-iphone-ipad) por Safari en móviles con iOS, por lo que para dar soporte para todos los navegadores, es recomendables uses alguna solución de terceros como [jquery datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) o cualquier otra que no sea la api nativa del navegador. Dado que preguntas exclusivamente por vanilla javascript, limité mi respuesta a ello.